# c++ pass functor and parameter to one Method

Tags: c++, oop, interface, functor

I have this to accomplish.

Function `DoJob()` would take different "`verify`" functor to verify things in different way.
It's possible to pass some variable such as "`message`" to verify function.
Or, it's possible not to pass any parameter to verify function.

and, now, `DoJob` is a function of a singleton class. I can use `getInstance()` anywhere to get this class.
Based on this, how do I define the `DoJob` and `verify` interface?

Thanks,

Comment: Can we see some code? It's hard to offer advice if we don't see what you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singleton class:

```
struct MySingleton
{
    static MySingleton* getInstance();

    // DoJob for verify functions that need a message.
    void DoJob(void (*verify)(std::string const&), std::string const& message)
    {
       verify(message);
    }

    // DoJob for verify functions that don't need a message.
    void DoJob(void (*verify)())
    {
       verify();
    }
};
```

A function to be used to verify.

```
void verify1(std::string const& message)
{
   // Do something with message
}
```

Use the singleton and the verify function.

```
MySingleton::getInstance()->DoJob(verify1, "A message");
```

Comment: Add an overloaded `DoJob`.

Comment: @R Sahu I got a trouble. When I use getInstance()->DoJob(verify1, "xx"), I got "verify1" is not defined. Should I use MySingleton::verify1 instead of verify1? But it says invalid use of non-static memeber function of verify1, But I don't want to make it static. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a C++11 variadic template to accomplish this.

```
class Foo {
    //... 
public:
    static Foo & getInstance() {
        static Foo instance;
        return instance;
    }
    template <typename V, typename ...X>
    void DoJob (V verify, X... x) {
        verify(x...);
    } 
};

struct Vvoid {
    void operator () (void) {}
};

struct Vstring {
    void operator () (std::string) {}
};

void Vfunction (void) {}

//...
    Foo &f = Foo::getInstance();
    f.DoJob(Vvoid());
    f.DoJob(Vstring(), "msg");
    f.DoJob(Vfunction);
```

Note that `Vvoid` and `Vstring` are true functors (object instances that can be called like a function with the `()` operator). But, the template syntax allows any callable instance to be passed in, including regular function pointers (e.g., `Vfunction`).

Follow the link for a [working demo.](http://ideone.com/hSi2Ub)